# Combine similar rows using case statement

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I have a query currently populating a report which has a few rows of "duplicate" information. Similar IDs are being passed through which should be combined but are unique enough that we do not want to `Concat`/`Insert` them within our model. In order for the report to be processed correctly, I need to sum their $ values (The only information I actually need to keep preserved is the name, the final Summed amount, and the ID.

Is there a simple way to achieve this by creating a case statement the solely will sum the `Amount` field? I tried using a `SUM(CASE WHEN` statement but I do not want a new column since my report is only using that field to populate $$ information. Here is a sample of my issue below:

```
ID          Name            Amount      Person
+-------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+
21011     Place A        -210.30       John Doe
210115    Place A-a      6500.70       John Doe
21060     Place B         255.00       Wayne C
2106015   Place Bb        212.30       Wayne C
2106015   Place Bb       1212.30       Wayne C
2106015   Place Bb        212.30       Wayne C
21080     Place J       57212.30       Billy J
```

My desired result for this would be:

```
ID          Name            Amount      Person
+-------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+
21011     Place A        6290.40       John Doe
21060     Place B        1889.90       Wayne C
21080     Place J       57212.30       Billy J
```

Is there a simplified way to combine these rows in TSQL without modifying the db?

Comment: How are you deciding on the `Name` and `ID` to be returned for each group. Is it the values of the first row in the group (I guess you want to group by the `Name` column)

Comment: I am taking the shorter ID value back - the 5 digit IDs.

Comment: So the `ID` column is actually a `varchar` field? What code have you written so far? Can we have a look at it?

Comment: Its a bit proprietary but its a pretty simple query getting columns from my FactTable and Inner joining to get DateIDs/CodeIDs/etc. For the most part this is what it looks like:

`SELECT ID,Name,BU,Amount
FROM FinanceTable INNER JOIN
Tenant...
DimProp...
DimDate...

WHERE  Amount <> '0' and DimProp.fMgmtID = '12345' AND (DimDate.Date = @ReportDate)  and Amount <> '0.00' and (@ReportDate = DimDate.Date) 
Order By ID Asc`

Comment: Does `GROUP BY` the first 5 characters of `ID` (using the `LEFT` function), `MIN` of `Name`, `SUM` of `Amount` and `MIN` of `Person` get you somewhere close?

Comment: @HABO I was almost able to somewhat accomplish this but ran into an issue. I created a case statement to Change 7digit IDs to 5 digits in a new column and grouped on the ID because the rows would all roll up the $$amounts as I would like however, I have a date field which is inconsistent. This caused my logic to break since the report uses a DueDate field to bucket bills that are 1-30, 31-60, 61-90+ days over due. (Since this is an AR report)

Thus, the dates caused the report to return the rows without the changes :/

Comment: Sounds like you either need to update your question to include the `DueDate` aging or start a new question. You can use `sum( case when 31 <= DueDate <= 60 then Amount else 0 end ) as Aged31To60` to sum into a bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (provided your `ID` column is a number and not a character field):

```
;WITH cte_getsum AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum,
ID,
NAME, 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM TableName WHERE TableName.Person = t1.Person) AS SumAmount,
Person
FROM
TableName t1
)
SELECT * FROM cte_getsum
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below script, I created a temp table just for sample Data.. but in your case you can directly refer to table you have.

```
SELECT * INTO #tmpInput 
FROM (VALUES('21011','Place A',  -210.30,'John Doe'),
('210115','Place A-a',6500.70,'John Doe'),
('21060',  'Place B'  ,255.00,'Wayne C'),
('2106015', 'Place Bb' ,212.30,'Wayne C'),
('2106015' , 'Place Bb' ,1212.30,'Wayne C'),
('2106015' ,  'Place Bb' ,212.30 ,'Wayne C')
,('21080'   ,  'Place J'  ,57212.30,'Billy J')
)Input (ID,Name,Amount,Person)



SELECT SUBSTRING(t1.ID,0,6) ID
       ,t2.Name 
       ,SUM(t1.Amount) AMOUNT
       ,t2.Person    
FROM #tmpInput t1
INNER JOIN #tmpInput t2 ON t2.ID=SUBSTRING(t1.ID,0,6)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(t1.ID,0,6),t2.Name,t2.Person
```